# Highcharts selection event not passing xAxis

Tags: highcharts

Im working on a chart that has multiple data sources that dynamically load based on a zoomed range, but for some reason the chart "selection" event never passes an xAxis so I can get the range of the selection to then reload the data for the appropriate zoom-level. Since what I was trying to do was a little complex to debug, I reduced the case to a single static dataset that only performs a console.log(e) on the selection event.  My distilled example is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/j5z5E/

When I do a selection on this sample chart, nothing zooms and the JavaScript Console shows the event has the xAxis and yAxis arrays, but the xAxis is 0-length and the yAxis is 1-length.

I see the check in the examples all the time:

```
if (e.xAxis[0]) {
    //do stuff
}
```

So obviously there are situations where the xAxis would not be passed. Am I doing something to trigger such a situation? I know I must have done something wrong, but I cant for the life of me figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your min and max values are not numbers but date strings. When casting them to timestamp numbers, it works.

```
var start = +new Date(2013, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var end = +new Date(2013, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j5z5E/11/)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you set:

```
xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
     min: start,
     max: end,
     minRange: 3600000      
},
```

which set min and max values which does not let chart zoom as it already define min and max values.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/j5z5E/1/)

Comment: Thats interesting, the documentation mentions nothing about that. It seems perfectly reasonable to me to expect a selection event with an xAxis even if the min/max were specified (a selection may not always be for zooming). I might file a bug/feature-request on this then.